# Updating both a ConcurrentHashMap and an AtomicInteger safely

Tags: java, concurrency, concurrenthashmap

I have to store words and their corresponding integer indices in a hash map. The hash map will be updated concurrently.

For example: lets say the `wordList` is `{a,b,c,a,d,e,a,d,e,b}`
The the hash map will contain the following key-value pairs

```
a:1
b:2
c:3
d:4
e:5
```

The code for this is as follows:

```
public class Dictionary {

private ConcurrentMap<String, Integer>  wordToIndex;
private AtomicInteger                   maxIndex;

public Dictionary( int startFrom ) {
    wordToIndex = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Integer>();
    this.maxIndex = new AtomicInteger(startFrom);
}


public void insertAndComputeIndices( List<String> words ) {

    Integer index;
    //iterate over the list of words
    for ( String word : words ) {
        // check if the word exists in the Map
        // if it does not exist, increment the maxIndex and put it in the
        // Map if it is still absent
        // set the maxIndex to the newly inserted index

        if (!wordToIndex.containsKey(word)) {
            index = maxIndex.incrementAndGet();

            index = wordToIndex.putIfAbsent(word, index);
            if (index != null)
                maxIndex.set(index);
        }
    }
}
```

My question is whether the above class is thread safe or not?
Basically an atomic operation in this case should be to increment the `maxIndex` and then put the word in the hash map if it is absent.

Is there a better way to achieve concurrency in this situation?

Comment: `insertAndComputeIndices` just reeks of mixing of concerns, anything you have `somethingANDsomethingelse` as a method name, it is usually a bad thing. The `and` part should be an implementation detail and of no concern to the client code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clearly another thread can see `maxIndex` incrementing and then getting clobbered.

Assuming this is all that is going on to the map (in particular, no removes), then you could try putting the word in the map and only incrementing if that succeeds.

```
    Integer oldIndex = wordToIndex.putIfAbsent(word, -1);
    if (oldIndex == null) {
        wordToIndex.put(word, maxIndex.incrementAndGet());
    }
```

(Alternatively for a single `put`, use some sort of mutable type in place of `Integer`.)

Comment: this may not work....if thread A and B see oldIndex as null, then both threads may first increment maxIndex and then put the word...hence i will not see continuous maxIndex...correct me if wrong

Answer (score 3):

No, it is not. If you have two methods A and B, both thread safe, this of course does not mean that calling A and B in a sequence is also thread safe, as a thread can interrupt another one between the function calls. This is what happens here:

```
    if (!wordToIndex.containsKey(word)) {
        index = maxIndex.incrementAndGet();

        index = wordToIndex.putIfAbsent(word, index);
        if (index != null)
            maxIndex.set(index);
    }
```

Thread A verifies that wordToIndex does not contain the word "dog" and proceeds inside the if. Before it can add the word "dog", thread B also finds that "dog" is not in the map (A did not add it yet) so it also proceeds inside the if. Now you have the word "dog" trying to be inserted twice.

Of course, putIfAbsent will guarantee that only one thread can add it, but I think that your goal is to not have two threads enter the if at the same time with the same key.

Comment: my goal and also my concern is that maxIndex should not be incremented twice for the same word (which is possible in the above scenario)... if thread A and B try to put "dog", both can reach inside if block but then both might increment maxIndex thus i will have one index waster...this is what i want to avoid

Answer (score 0):

[AtomicInteger](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) is something you should consider using.

And you should wrap all the code that needs to happen as a `transaction` in a `synchronized(this)` block.

Comment: i am already using AtomicInteger...if I were to use a synchronized block then i would straightaway use HashMap and not ConcurrentHashMap and i will have a good solution...but i guess i want to use ConcurrentHashMap

Comment: `ConcurrentHashMap` doesn't mean what you think it means, it means that the **individual** methods are `synchronized` against **themselves** but if you are calling them individually in sequence you still have to wrap what **you intend** on being an atomic transaction in `synchronized` there is **no magic** behind this.

Answer (score 0):

The other answers are correct --- there are non-thread-safe fields in your class.  What you should do, to start, is make sure

**how to implement the threading**

1) I would make sure everything internal is private, although this is not a requirement of thread-safe code.

2) Find any of your accessor methods, make sure they are snychronized whenever the state of the global object is modified (OR AT LEAST THE IF BLOCK IS SYNCHRONIZED).

3) Test for deadlocks or bad counts, this can be implemented in a unit test by making sure the value of maxIndex is correct after 10000 threaded inserts, for example...